# How to implement a diagonal data for a linear layer in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I would like to have a network in pytorch that only scale the data.

The mathematical notations for my request is:
[image]

which means that if my input is `[1, 2]` and my output is [2, 6].
then the linear layer will look like this:

```
[ [ 2, 0],
  [ 0, 3] ].
```

I have this network written in pytorch:

```
class ScalingNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, output_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=input_shape, out_features=output_shape)
        self.mask = torch.diag(torch.ones(input_shape))
        self.linear_layer.weight.data = self.linear_layer.weight * self.mask
        self.linear_layer.weight.requires_grad = True

    def get_tranformation_matrix(self):
        return self.linear_layer.weight


    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.linear_layer(X)
        return X
```

But at the end of the training, my self.linear is not diagonal.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an apparent constraint here is the fact that `self.linear_layer` needs to be a squared matrix. You can use the diagonal matrix `self.mask` to zero out all non-diagonal elements in the forward pass:

```
class ScalingNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, in_features, bias=False)
        self.mask = torch.eye(in_features, dtype=bool)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.linear.weight.data *= self.mask
        print(self.linear.weight)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x
```

For instance:

```
>>> m = ScalingNetwork(5)

>>> m(torch.rand(1,5))
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.2987, -0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000],
        [ 0.0000, -0.1042, -0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000],
        [-0.0000,  0.0000, -0.4267,  0.0000, -0.0000],
        [ 0.0000, -0.0000, -0.0000,  0.1758,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.0000, -0.3208]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[-0.1032, -0.0087, -0.1709,  0.0035, -0.1496]], grad_fn=<MmBackward0>)
```